# Funciones en c++

Tags: c++, funciones

Dada una funcion para leer un fichero, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al hacer la llamada de la función en el programa principal, este se cierre cuando el fichero no existe?

De momento tengo hecho esto:

```
int leer_correo (int cart[], int certif[], int paq[]){
    FILE *fe;
    int i, anyo, total[ANYOS];
    if((fe=fopen("correo.txt", "r"))==NULL){
        printf("Error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for(i=0 ; i<ANYOS ; i++)
        fscanf(fe, "%d%d%d%d", &anyo, &cart[i], &certif[i], &paq[i]);
    total[anyo-1900]=cart[anyo-1900]+certif[anyo-1900]+paq[anyo-1900];
    return 0;
}

void main(){
    int opc, cart[ANYOS], certif[ANYOS], paq[ANYOS];    
    leer_correo(); // Llamar a la función leer correo
    // Si hay error: terminar el programa
}
```

Comment: ¿El código es C o C++? Asumo que C++ por la etiqueta que has puesto pero no usas ninguna facilidad de C++.

Comment: `if (leer_correo() == -1) { terminar programa } else { seguir programa }`

Answer (score 1):

Debieras aclarar si estás usando C o C++, la etiquta dice C++ pero tu código es de ANSI C.

Puedes utilizar la función [exit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/) para finalizar tu proceso, indicando un código de estado que te servirá para identificar el motivo.

```
#define NO_CORREO         -1
#define RESULTADO_NOFILE   1

void main() // Cambia el tipo de 
{
    int opc, cart[ANYOS], certif[ANYOS], paq[ANYOS];    
    if( leer_correo() == NO_CORREO ) // Llamar a la función leer correo
        exit(RESULTADO_NOFILE);      // Salida con código 1

    // Haz el resto de cosas que tengas que hacer.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias formas de notificar un error:

**Usar un código de error**

Esto se puede hacer con `#define` o con `enum`. Mi preferencia personal sería la segunda opción por varias razones:

- Los enumerados generan una identificación diferente para cada elemento de forma automática, reduce el riesgo de tener identificadores repetidos
- A partir de C++11 (ver tercer ejemplo), a los enumerados se les puede proporcionar un tipado fuerte. La gran ventaja de activar esta característica es que proporcionamos un código más robusto.

Ejemplo con `#define`:

```
#define OK 0
#define FILE_NOT_FOUND 1
#define ANOTHER 2
// ...

int TestFunc()
{
  return FILE_NOT_FOUND;
}

int main()
{
  switch( TestFunc() )
  {
    case OK:
      std::cout << "Ok\n";
      break;

    case FILE_NOT_FOUND:
      std::cout << "Fichero no encontrado\n";
      break;

    // ...
  }
}
```

Ejemplo con `enum`:

```
enum TestFuncReturn
{
  OK,
  FILE_NOT_FOUND,
  ANOTHER,
  // ...
};

TestFuncReturn TestFunc()
{
  return FILE_NOT_FOUND;
}

int main()
{
  switch( TestFunc() )
  {
    case OK:
      std::cout << "Ok\n";
      break;

    case FILE_NOT_FOUND:
      std::cout << "Fichero no encontrado\n";
      break;

    // ...
  }
}
```

Ejemplo con `enum` en C++11:

```
enum class TestFuncReturn
{
  OK,
  FILE_NOT_FOUND,
  ANOTHER,
  // ...
};

TestFuncReturn TestFunc()
{
  return TestFuncReturn::FILE_NOT_FOUND;
}

int main()
{
  switch( TestFunc() )
  {
    case TestFuncReturn::OK:
      std::cout << "Ok\n";
      break;

    case TestFuncReturn::FILE_NOT_FOUND:
      std::cout << "Fichero no encontrado\n";
      break;

    // ...
  }
}
```

**Excepciones:**

Usar códigos de error tiene varios inconvenientes:

- ocupan el `return` de la función, por lo que para devolver información adicional toca recurrir a artificios como parámetros por referencia o al uso de `std::pair` o `std::tuple`.
- Muchas veces la función que recibe el mensaje de error no puede hacer nada por sí misma para recuperar la situación, le toca propagar el error hacia arriba y eso provoca que haya que tener especial cuidado para que diferentes mensajes de error no se solapen.
- Devolver un código de error en ocasiones se antoja insuficiente para, por ejemplo, informar al usuario acerca del problema (¿Qué fichero ha fallado?,¿Por qué motivo?,¿Hay algo más que haya que tener en cuenta?).

Para suplir estas deficiencias existen las exepciones. Las excepciones pueden (y deberían) ser objetos, lo cual permite aprovechar características de herencia, polimorfismo y encapsulación para proporcionar toda la información que sea necesaria para poder recuperarse de un error.

Ejemplo C++98:

```
class FileNotFoundException : public std::exception
{
  public:

    FileNotFoundException(const std::string& mensaje)
      : m_error(mensaje)
    { }

    const char* what() const
    { return m_error.c_str(); }
  private:

    std::string m_error;
};

class AnotherException : public std::exception
{
  public:

    AnotherException (const std::string& mensaje)
      : m_error(mensaje)
    { }

    const char* what() const
    { return m_error.c_str(); }
  private:

    std::string m_error;
};

void TestFunc()
{
  throw FileNotFoundException("No se pudo encontrar el fichero notas.txt");
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    TestFunc();
  }

  catch( const std::exception& exc )
  {
    std::cout << "Error: " << exc.what();
  }
}
```

Ejemplo C++11:

```
class FileNotFoundException : public std::exception
{
  public:

    FileNotFoundException(std::string const& mensaje) noexcept
      : m_error(mensaje)
    { }

    const char* what() const noexcept override
    { return m_error.c_str(); }
  private:

    std::string m_error;
};

class AnotherException : public std::exception
{
  public:

    AnotherException (std::string const& mensaje) noexcept
      : m_error(mensaje)
    { }

    const char* what() const noexcept override
    { return m_error.c_str(); }

  private:

    std::string m_error;
};

void TestFunc()
{
  throw FileNotFoundException("No se pudo encontrar el fichero notas.txt");
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    TestFunc();
  }

  // Solo captura FileNotFoundException
  catch( const FileNotFoundException& exc )
  {
    std::cout << "Error de fichero: " << exc.what();
  }

  // Captura cualquier excepción que herede de std::exception
  // excepto FileNotFoundException, que está capturada en el catch anterior
  catch( const std::exception& exc )
  {
    std::cout << "Error: " << exc.what();
  }
}
```

Ejemplos con `enum` o `#define` no te voy a poner porque ya tienes otras respuestas cubriendo ese ámbito.

Te pongo un ejemplo incorporando excepciones. También he retocado un poco el código para dejarlo más acorde a lo que se espera de un código C++ más o menos moderno (ausencia de arreglos crudos, variables declaradas en su momento, uso de la entrada/salida propia de C++, ...). Lo único que no he modificado es el uso del fichero... eso sí, recuerda que debes cerrar el fichero antes de abandonar la función.

```
class FileNotFoundException : public std::exception
{
  public:

    FileNotFoundException(const std::string& mensaje)
      : m_error(mensaje)
    { }

    const char* what() const
    { return m_error.c_str(); }
  private:

    std::string m_error;
};

struct Datos
{
  cart;
  certif;
  paq;
};

typedef std::array<Datos,ANYOS> VectorDatos;

VectorDatos leer_correo ()
{
  VectorDatos datos;
  FILE *fe;

  if((fe=fopen("correo.txt", "r"))==NULL){
    throw FileNotFoundException("Error al abrir correo.txt");
  }

  for(int i=0 ; i<ANYOS ; i++)
  {
    int anyo;
    Datos& item = datos[i];
    fscanf(fe, "%d%d%d%d", &anyo, &item.cart, &item.certif, &item.paq);
  }

  fclose(fe);

  return datos;
}

void main(){
  std::array<Datos,ANYOS> datos;

  try
  {    
    datos = leer_correo(); // Llamar a la función leer correo
  }

  catch( const FileNotFoundException& exc )
  {
    std::cout << "Error: " << exc.what();

    // Si otro programa está esperando a que éste devuelva una respuesta
    // entonces el valor de este código es importante. En caso contrario
    // es irrelevante.
    return -1; 
  }

  // Resto del main
  // ...
}
```

El código debería ser compatible con C++98. Lo he intentado hacer así a propósito porque viendo tu código no creo que estés compilando con C++11 o C++14.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias, en el main, chequear el resultado del método leer_corre para ver si hubo error o no de la siguiente forma:

```
    #define ERROR_READ_FILE      -1
    #define SUCCESS_READ_FILE    1

    int leer_correo (int cart[], int certif[], int paq[]){
        FILE *fe;
        int i, anyo, total[ANYOS];
        if((fe=fopen("correo.txt", "r"))==NULL){
            printf("Error\n");
            return ERROR_READ_FILE;
        }

        for(i=0 ; i<ANYOS ; i++)
            fscanf(fe, "%d%d%d%d", &anyo, &cart[i], &certif[i], &paq[i]);
        total[anyo-1900]=cart[anyo-1900]+certif[anyo-1900]+paq[anyo-1900];
        return SUCCESS_READ_FILE;
    }

    void main(){
        int opc, cart[ANYOS], certif[ANYOS], paq[ANYOS];    
        if (leer_correo() == ERROR_READ_FILE) // Llamar a la función leer correo
            exit(0); // Si hay error: terminar el programa
    }
```

Espero te sea de utilidad!